# How to display total number of users on Active Admin User page (rails 3.2, active admin gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I managed to install active admin and I can see the users with the following table:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

index do   
    selectable_column                         
column :email                     
column :created_at
column :confirmed_at  
column :last_sign_in_at           
column :last_sign_in_ip
column :sign_in_count     

default_actions                   
end  

filter :email
filter :created_at
filter :confirmed_at
filter :last_sign_in_at 
filter :sign_in_count

end
```

I would like at the top of my page to display the total number of users.

How can I do it? Should I do it on admin/user.rb or modify another page (a view page?)

Answer (score 2):

In view page where you want to show put code User.count (This show total no of user)